Is there a way to retrieve raydium's pool keys with timestamp going back x amount of time?
As the title says, I'm looking for a way to retrieve these for a specified amount of time or from the current block until block x in the past.
The json file they are providing for download has ~380k entries and they are ordered alphabetically by id with no timestamp.
Preferably without having to iterate over thousands of transactions.
I suppose getting a list of addresses for the base or lp token could also work and then I would be filtering those from the JSON file.
